# pre-commit hook in svn: could not be translated from the native locale to UTF-8

Tags: svn, utf-8, hook

I have a problem with my pre-commit hook.

This hook test if a file is locked when the user commits. When a bad condition happens, it should output that the another user is locking this file or if nobody is locking, it should show "you are not locking this file message (file´s name)". The error happens when the file´s name has some latin character like "ç" and tortoise show me this in the output.

Commit failed (details follow): 
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output: 
[Erro output could not be translated from the native locale to UTF-8.]

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thanks,

Alexandre

My shell script is here:

`#!/bin/sh`
`REPOS="$1"`
`TXN="$2"`
`export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`
`/app/svn/hooks/ensure-has-need-lock.pl "$REPOS" "$TXN"`
`if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 1; fi`
`exit 0`

And my perl is here:

```
!/usr/bin/env perl  

#Turn on warnings the best way depending on the Perl version.   
BEGIN {   
  if ( $] >= 5.006_000)   
    { require warnings; import warnings; }                         
  else     
    { $^W = 1; }                  
}              

use strict;   
use Carp;   

&usage unless @ARGV == 2;   

my $repos        = shift;   
my $txn          = shift;    

my $svnlook = "/usr/local/bin/svnlook";   
my $user;   

my $ok = 1;   
  foreach my $program ($svnlook)   
    {   
      if (-e $program)   
        {   
          unless (-x $program)   
            {   
              warn "$0: required program $program' is not executable, ",   
                   "edit $0.\n";   
              $ok = 0;   
            }   
        }   
      else   
        {   
          warn "$0: required program $program' does not exist, edit $0.\n";   
          $ok = 0;   
        }   
    }   
  exit 1 unless $ok;   

  unless (-e $repos){   
      &usage("$0: repository directory $repos' does not exist.");   
  }   
  unless (-d $repos){   
      &usage("$0: repository directory $repos' is not a directory.");   
  }   

  foreach my $user_tmp (&read_from_process($svnlook, 'author', $repos, '-t', $txn))   
  {   
      $user = $user_tmp;   
  }   
  my @errors;           

  foreach my $transaction (&read_from_process($svnlook, 'changed', $repos, '-t', $txn)){  
    if ($transaction =~ /^U.  (.*[^\/])$/){   
      my $file = $1;   
      my $err = 0;   
      foreach my $locks (&read_from_process($svnlook, 'lock', $repos, $file)){   
        $err = 1;   
        if($locks=~ /Owner: (.*)/){   
          if($1 != $user){   
           push @errors, "$file : You are not locking this file!";    
          }   
        }   
      }   
      if($err==0){   
        push @errors, "$file : You are not locking this file!";   
      }   
    }   
    elsif($transaction =~ /^D.  (.*[^\/])$/){   
      my $file = $1;   
      my $tchan = &read_from_process($svnlook, 'lock', $repos, $file);   
      foreach my $locks (&read_from_process($svnlook, 'lock', $repos, $file)){   
        push @errors, "$1 : cannot delete locked Files";   
      }   
    }   
    elsif($transaction =~ /^A.  (.*[^\/])$/){   
      my $needs_lock;   
      my $path = $1;   
      foreach my $prop (&read_from_process($svnlook, 'proplist', $repos, '-t', $txn, '--verbose', $path)){   
          if ($prop =~ /^\s*svn:needs-lock : (\S+)/){   
            $needs_lock = $1;   
          }   
      }   
      if (not $needs_lock){   
        push @errors, "$path : svn:needs-lock is not set. Pleas ask TCC for support.";   
      }   
    }   
  }   
if (@errors)   
  {   
    warn "$0:\n\n",   
         join("\n", @errors), "\n\n";   
    exit 1;   
  }   
else   
  {   
    exit 0;   
  }   

sub usage   
{   
  warn "@_\n" if @_;   
  die "usage: $0 REPOS TXN-NAME\n";   
}   

sub safe_read_from_pipe   
{   
  unless (@_)   
    {   
      croak "$0: safe_read_from_pipe passed no arguments.\n";   
    }   
  print "Running @_\n";   
  my $pid = open(SAFE_READ, '-|');   
  unless (defined $pid)   
    {   
      die "$0: cannot fork: $!\n";   
    }   
  unless ($pid)   
    {   
      open(STDERR, ">&STDOUT")   
        or die "$0: cannot dup STDOUT: $!\n";   
      exec(@_)   
        or die "$0: cannot exec @_': $!\n";   
    }   
  my @output;   
  while (<SAFE_READ>)   
    {   
      chomp;   
      push(@output, $_);   
    }   
  close(SAFE_READ);   
  my $result = $?;   
  my $exit   = $result >> 8;   
  my $signal = $result & 127;   
  my $cd     = $result & 128 ? "with core dump" : "";   
  if ($signal or $cd)   
    {   
      warn "$0: pipe from @_' failed $cd: exit=$exit signal=$signal\n";   
    }   
  if (wantarray)   
    {   
      return ($result, @output);   
    }   
  else   
    {   
      return $result;   
    }   
}   

sub read_from_process   
  {   
  unless (@_)   
    {   
      croak "$0: read_from_process passed no arguments.\n";   
    }   
  my ($status, @output) = &safe_read_from_pipe(@_);   
  if ($status)   
    {   
      if (@output)   
        {   
          die "$0: @_' failed with this output:\n", join("\n", @output), "\n";   
        }   
      else   
        {   
          die "$0: @_' failed with no output.\n";   
        }   
    }   
  else   
    {   
      return @output;   
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think it would be valuable to see the source of the perl script as well. Why do you assume the error is not in there?

Comment: I think the error is on shell or on tortoise(I don´t know) beucause if the shell only contains this:

echo "testç" 1>&2

the same error happens.

But I will put my perl code.

Comment: I´m looking for this solution for 5 days and I can´t found. Maybe this is a bug or something.
If somebody has any idea about what is happening, or if it is a bug or if it happened with somebody.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe put the perl code in a code block so it will be easier to read?

Comment: Like I said, the problem isn´t my perl script. If I put echo "testç" 1>&2 inside my shell, the same problem occurs. I think that TortoiseSVN doesn´t understand the "ç" character if I return it from a hook script.

Answer (score 6):

This is a known subversion bug, I just hit as well.
http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2487

To solve my problem I used vi and did the following

I usually do a :set hls (highlight search results) followed by /[^ -~] 
(search for any character that is not between space and tilde, ie. that 
is not a printable character from the ASCII set.)  You can add the tab 
character (with Ctrl-V Tab) inside the square brackets if you use it in 
your documents.  It will show as /[^ -~^I] with a blue ^I.

found a u in Cancun that had an accent but was actually not a legal latin-1 character.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this (on debian) by editing the /etc/apache2/envvars
and set the apache to run with the machine locale (the default is C):

```
## The locale used by some modules like mod_dav
export LANG=C
## Uncomment the following line to use the system default locale instead:
#. /etc/default/locale
```

^---- uncomment this line to set the system locale in apache.

if you are not using a UTF-8 locale, manually set a UTF-8 locale
just for apache:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue and it was happening because I was using some special characters in my commit message.
I just removed those characters and it worked like charm.

Specially look for apostrophe characters (when u have text copied from word document or so).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following line in your httpd.conf file.

`SVNUseUTF8 on`

are you using CentOS? this maybe some OS issue, since it is almost impossible to find this tip only with Google.

Answer (score 0):

In the post commit script or the commit message look for " or ' and check them if they are in UTF-8 format. 
If not change them and run it worked for me.